# Avoid matches with given text in fixed position

Tags: c#, regex

I'm have two kinds of string (`something` could be any kind of text):

- `<<something>>`
- `<<CODE:something>>`

The patterns of the Regex used to find both are:

- `<<(.*?)>>`
- `<<CODE:(.*?)>>`

As you can see, there's an issue that the first pattern can also find the second string.
Since both start with `<<` and the first pattern is `(.*?)`, it's possible get an unwanted match.

How can I prevent finding strings with `CODE:` while still inside `<< >>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```cs
<<(?!CODE:)(.*?)>>
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/mJBOdG/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <<                       '<<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CODE:                    'CODE:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >>                       '>>'
```